# MS SQL Error "Invalid object name" on table I just created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an

> invalid object name

error when I try to insert records into a table that I just created.

I am using `Microsoft SQL 2000`. I am testing all of this on the super user account, so there are no permissions issues.

### Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [table_test2] (
[User 4] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[User 3] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[User 2] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[User 1] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Spouse] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Sensitivity] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Referred By] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Profession] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Private] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Priority] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Address PO Box] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Organizational ID Number] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Office Location] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Notes] [varchar] (133)  NULL ,  
[Mileage] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Manager's Name] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Location] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Language] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Keywords] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Internet Free Busy] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Initials] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Address PO Box] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Hobby] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Government ID Number] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Gender] [varchar] (16)  NULL ,  
[E-mail 3 Display Name] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail 3 Type] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail 3 Address] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail 2 Display Name] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail 2 Type] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail 2 Address] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail Display Name] [varchar] (38)  NULL ,  
[E-mail Type] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[E-mail Address] [varchar] (38)  NULL ,  
[Directory Server] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Children] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Categories] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business Address PO Box] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Birthday] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Billing Information] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Assistant's Name] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Anniversary] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Account] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Telex] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[TTY/TDD Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Radio Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Primary Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Pager] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Fax] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Mobile Phone] [varchar] (19)  NULL ,  
[ISDN] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Phone 2] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Fax] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Company Main Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Car Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Callback] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business Phone 2] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business Phone] [varchar] (19)  NULL ,  
[Business Fax] [varchar] (19)  NULL ,  
[Assistant's Phone] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Country/Region] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Postal Code] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other State] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other City] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Street 3] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Street 2] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Other Street] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Country/Region] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Postal Code] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home State] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home City] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Street 3] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Street 2] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Home Street] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business Country/Region] [varchar] (29)  NULL ,  
[Business Postal Code] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business State] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business City] [varchar] (17)  NULL ,  
[Business Street 3] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business Street 2] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Business Street] [varchar] (30)  NULL ,  
[Job Title] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Department] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Company] [varchar] (34)  NULL ,  
[Suffix] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Last Name] [varchar] (16)  NULL ,  
[Middle Name] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[First Name] [varchar] (10)  NULL ,  
[Title] [varchar] (10)  NULL 
)
```

No errors creating the table!!

### I can select from the table:

```
select * from table_test2
```

### But when I try to insert, I get an error that the object is not fonud:

```
insert into table_test2
('User 4', 'User 3', 'User 2')
values
('a','b','c')
```

### Returns error:

> Server: Msg 208, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Invalid object name
>   'table_test'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't have the same name though. The one you have created has a `2` suffix.

```
CREATE TABLE [table_test2]
```

And

```
select * from table_test
```

If you are sure you weren't making a similar error with your select/insert statements I would suggest running the following.

```
select * from 
sysobjects /*For SQL Server 2000*/
where name like 'table_test%'
```

Additionally your `insert` statement looks dodgy. I think you would need square brackets or double quotes not single quotes. I'm not sure if that could produce the error you were seeing.

```
insert into table_test
([User 4], [User 3], [User 2])
values
('a','b','c')
```

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error. The table names match and I still get the error.
The table is found in the sysobject table. Which is sysobjects, not sys.objects.

Comment: @jsjoy - Good point SQL2000 uses sysobjects. What about the square brackets? You definitely can't use single quotes there.

Comment: yep, that's it. I kept focusing on the fact that it says the table is not found. Silly syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you are using the correct database?  Try using the `USE` statement right before each, or prefixing the table with the name of the database, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE mydatabase..table_name  ...
INSERT INTO mydatabase..table_name ...
```

The '..' prefix can be used so you don't need to specify the schema (e.g. `dbo`).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error. Need to wrap the insert statement column list with brackets rather than quotes:

this would be the proper syntax:

```
 insert into table_test2
    ([User 4], [User 3], [User 2])
    values
    ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CREATE TABLE statement, the name of the table is table_test2

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the post. The table names are the same when I try it.